# Successive prime numbers in R

Tags: r, primes

I'm using RStudio and am pretty new to R. I have a dataset that shows the prime numbers from 1- 301. How do you use the diff function to compute the differences between successive primes?

Here is my dataset:

```
 [1]    2    3    5    7   11   13   17   19   23   29   31   37   41   43   47   53   59   61   67   71   73   79   83   89   97  101  103  107  109  113
 [31]  127  131  137  139  149  151  157  163  167  173  179  181  191  193  197  199  211  223  227  229  233  239  241  251  257  263  269  271  277  281
 [61]  283  293  307  311  313  317  331  337  347  349  353  359  367  373  379  383  389  397  401  409  419  421  431  433  439  443  449  457  461  463
 [91]  467  479  487  491  499  503  509  521  523  541  547  557  563  569  571  577  587  593  599  601  607  613  617  619  631  641  643  647  653  659
[121]  661  673  677  683  691  701  709  719  727  733  739  743  751  757  761  769  773  787  797  809  811  821  823  827  829  839  853  857  859  863
[151]  877  881  883  887  907  911  919  929  937  941  947  953  967  971  977  983  991  997 1009 1013 1019 1021 1031 1033 1039 1049 1051 1061 1063 1069
[181] 1087 1091 1093 1097 1103 1109 1117 1123 1129 1151 1153 1163 1171 1181 1187 1193 1201 1213 1217 1223 1229 1231 1237 1249 1259 1277 1279 1283 1289 1291
[211] 1297 1301 1303 1307 1319 1321 1327 1361 1367 1373 1381 1399 1409 1423 1427 1429 1433 1439 1447 1451 1453 1459 1471 1481 1483 1487 1489 1493 1499 1511
[241] 1523 1531 1543 1549 1553 1559 1567 1571 1579 1583 1597 1601 1607 1609 1613 1619 1621 1627 1637 1657 1663 1667 1669 1693 1697 1699 1709 1721 1723 1733
[271] 1741 1747 1753 1759 1777 1783 1787 1789 1801 1811 1823 1831 1847 1861 1867 1871 1873 1877 1879 1889 1901 1907 1913 1931 1933 1949 1951 1973 1979 1987
[301] 1993 1997 1999 2003
```

Would appreciate some help, thanks!

Comment: use `diff(myVec)`. That's it. If this answers your question, I'd suggest you delete it as it will probably lead to some down votes for little research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply call

```
diff(primes)
```

For a simple dataset:

```
> primes <- c(2,3,5,7)
> diff(primes)
[1] 1 2 2
```

Comment: oh ok thank you, it works!